# Using vc++ libraries in a MinGW QT project

Tags: qt, visual-c++, com, mingw

So have a user interface that I wrote using MinGW QT. In the UI I'm trying to reference objects from my Visual Studio project. Some objects I can reference and use just fine, but the one I'm having problems with uses a 3rd party COM object.

These are the errors I'm getting:

```
undefined reference to 'CoInitialize@4'
undefined reference to 'CoCreateInstance@20'
```

I've read that you can't easily mix MinGW and VS libraries. The catch is, Some of the GUI libraries I'm using only compile with MinGW, so I can't just change QT to use the Microsoft compiler.

Is there any way I can get it to recognize these functions, or am I going to end up having to rewrite everything?

I've tried including the 3rd party dll in the .pro file, but that doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are linking errors, you just need to link with whatever lib has the COM functions (ole32 according to a quick google). You can probably call code in a dll compiled with msvc from mingw, as long as it's C code not C++ though.

Answer (score 0):

MSVC and MinGW are not ABI compatible, so you need to compile all modules with same compiler to avoid this kind of problems.